# How can I using Cauchy's integral to calculate this integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Calculate $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(z) dz = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{e^{-\frac{(z-a)^2}{b^2}}}{(z+c)(z-c)}~dx,$ where $ x_1<a<x_2 ,b<x_1<x_2, x_1<c<x_2$.

I think.

$ \int_c f(z) dz = \int_xf(x)dx+\int_{0}^{-\pi}f(z)dz$

Please tell me how can I do?